# Class for storing personal details, inc. bank account info, in PHP (Mcrypt) - is this ok? How could it be improved?

Tags: php, security, cryptography, credit-card, mcrypt

I've been given the task of writing an encryption function that'll let my boss easily encrypt various bits of data to go into a database. This will include <strike>credit card details</strike> bank account information.
I've never used encryption within PHP before so am a touch worried.

Here's what I've done so far with the help of O'reilly's Essential PHP Security:
http://pastebin.com/7L2GxPNJ

The IV doesn't actually seem to do anything, which concerns me. Why's that?

Would appreciate it very much if someone could look through this code and check it out. I've spoken to a friend who reckons it'd be better off written as a daemon on another server that PHP would then connect to, however that can't be done *yet* - I'm just following orders.

For the moment, are there any improvements that could be made? What's the deal with the IV?

Thanks.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if you intend to store credit card details (incidentally, this is in all likelyhood a very, very bad idea), you'll need to be PCI compliant. See http://www.pcisecuritystandards.org for more information.

Comment: Thanks. It's not a regular e-commerce application or whatever, we're developing for a large firm that has to store the details (though have looked at integrating with other companies, PayPal, etc).

Comment: What's the PHP version? What do you mean by IV doesn't do anything?

Comment: 5.2. When I comment out line 78, or set a random IV there, it doesn't seem to have an effect. It just decrypts anyway.

Comment: Before 5.3 you need srand, but not for MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM I guess. No ideas yet.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you are developing for, if you store credit card info you are at risk. If you have not looked at PCI standards you better look now before you spend too much time on this. Auth.net, Paypal, etc spend MILLIONS meeting PCI standards.

Comment: Brent, I totally agree with you. I will do my best to encourage my boss to go with such but at the end of the day - orders are orders. I'll look into the PCI standards, though.

Comment: Just been told that no credit card details will be stored - only bank account details. Does this change anything?

Answer (score 0):

> The IV doesn't actually seem to do anything, which concerns me. Why's that?

An initialization vector is rather important - particularly when encrypting lots of small fragemnts of data. Somethnig is amiss if the encrypted data is not modified by the IV. And if you're storing the encryption key on the same filesystem as the encrypted data, it's just security by obscurity.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. There has to be something up. I'll take a look. As for security by obscurity, totally agree - so how can I get round that? Would the daemon be the best approach? Or would just running the PHP script on a separate webserver be ok?